# Two intersection points between $x^2 + ax + 2$ and the line segment that connects $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$

Tags: discriminant

If the parabola $x^2 + ax + 2$ and the line segment connecting the points $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$ (including the two endpoints) intersect 2 times at distinct points, find the range of $a.$

---

I've determined that $a = -2$ seems to be the only currently working number, but I'm not sure how to prove it. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Look at the discriminant of the quadratic given by the intersection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple to see that the line segment is $f: [0,2]\to [1,3]: f(x)=x+1$

We equate this to your curve: $$x^2+ax+2=x+1\implies x^2+(a-1)x+1=0$$

This has the solutions (by QF): $$x=\frac{(1-a)\pm\sqrt{(a-1)^2-4}}{2}=\frac{(1-a)\pm\sqrt{a^2-2a-3}}{2}\tag1$$
It has two unique, real solutions whenever the discriminant, $a^2-2a-3>0$. i.e. $a<-1, a>3$

Now you must take into consideration that the solutions must exist in the domain $[0,2]$. Use this to tighten your range.

---

When $a>3$, suppose $a=3+t$ for $t>0$, using $(1)$ we have $$x=\frac{-(t+2)\pm\sqrt{t(t+4)}}{2}<0$$
by [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means). (See if you can spot how)

When $a<-1$, again say $a=-(1+t), t>0$, we get $$x=\frac{(t+2)\pm\sqrt{t(t+4)}}{2}>0$$

for the same reason. Our solutions exist in this range, but after a certain point, where the second intersection is at the very end of the line segment, every other solution is too large.

Thus, we need to find the $a$ for which the second intersection meets at $(2,3)$, as anything beyond that will be out of our range. It's easy to see that $4+2a+2=3\implies a =-1.5$
and so our range is $$a \in [-1.5, -1)$$

Comment: Actually, how do I tighten my range, as I don't know how to relate $a$ and $x$ in such a manner that I could use the domain.

Comment: Added to my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Wait, but $-2$ also works.

Comment: When $a=-2$, our solution pairs are $$(x,y)=(1+\phi^\pm, 2+\phi^\pm)$$  where $\phi^\pm=\frac{1\pm\sqrt5}{2}$. The positive versions are outside the range, as $\phi^+\approx 1.618 > 1$. Recall that our condition is that $x\leq 2$ and $y\leq 3$

Comment: Yeah, but graph $x^2 - 2x + 2$ and take a look at their intersections with the line segment

Comment: [I did.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l1cup7j3wa). The orange square in that graph represents the restrictions on $x,y$, and so you have a solution whenever the red and purple lines intersect twice *inside* that square. You can check other values by scrolling the $a$, but notice when $a=-2$, the second intersection (at $(1+\phi^+, 2+\phi^+)$) falls outside that square.

Comment: Nevermind, I made a mistake in my graphing. Thanks!